Duplicating an object according to a variable in Visual Studio C# form
I am developing a project using Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2022.
In my project, I get the count value and I want to create GroupBoxes one under the other according to this value.
for(int i;i<count ; i++)
{
GroupBoxgroupBox =New GroupBox;
GroupBox.text="g1";
GroupBox.size(200.100);
GroupBox.location= New system.drawing.point(20,20+i*120);

this.panel1.controls.add(groupbox);
}


Mind telling us what your question is? (Outside making the code compile?)

^^ GroupBoxgroupBox =New GroupBox; needs to be (at least) GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox(); and in the lines following that one, GroupBox needs to be groupBox. Case does matter.

New system.drawing.point(20,20+i*120); => new System.Drawing.Point(20,20+i*120); and GroupBox.size(200.100); => groupBox.Size(200,100);

^^ All of which should be pointed out by your IDE.

Besides incompilable code example, to avoid manual positioning of controls take a look at FlowLayoutPanel control, which is container for other controls with auto-align support.

First, I hope you provide many details about your problem when asking so that everyone can help you.
Secondly, as Fildor mentioned, avoid manually specifying the locations of tools and use tools like FlowLayoutPanel to do so.
As for your problem, you just need to do the following:
    private void FillDataToPanel()
    { 
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new GroupBox()
            {
                Text = "g1",
                Size = new Size(200,100)
            });
        }
    }

